# migration from v3 to v4 - tooltip not showing in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

I created a scatter plot using [this](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/801c4bb101e86d19a1d0) reference. The code worked very well in v3 but after changing it to the v4, tooltip, x-axis and y-axis not showing up.

I created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rC6zjcOYX3IqN4vqEG0p?p=preview). I would appreciate it if someone can tell me what's wrong with it.

```
function showTooltip (d, i) {

    //Save the chosen circle (so not the voronoi)
    var element = d3.selectAll(".countries."+d.CountryCode);

    //Define and show the tooltip
    $(element).popover({
        placement: 'auto top',
        container: '#chart',
        trigger: 'manual',
        html : true,
        content: function() {
            return "<span style='font-size: 12px; text-align: center;'>" + "<span>" + "Speaker: " + "</span>" + d.Speaker + "\n"
            + "<span>" + "Duration: " + "</span>" + Math.round(d.Duration) + "\n" +"</span>"; }
    });
    $(element).popover('show');

    //Make chosen circle more visible
    element.style("opacity", 1)
        .style("stroke-width", 6);
```

**Update**:

[This](https://plnkr.co/edit/5alwonzCKi1iwubB3d1D?p=preview) is the corrected version for this scatter plot in v4 d3. I corrected it with the help of Lary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for :

> x-axis and y-axis not showing up

just remove :

```
 .axis .domain {
      display: none;
    }
```

from style

for :

> tooltip,lines

change inside showtooltip function:

```
var element = d3.select(".countries."+d.CountryCode);

    //Define and show the tooltip
    $(element.node()).popover({
        placement: 'auto top',
        container: '#chart',
        trigger: 'manual',
        html : true,
        content: function() {
            return "<span style='font-size: 12px; text-align: center;'>" + "<span>" + "Speaker: " + "</span>" + d.Speaker + "\n"
            + "<span>" + "Duration: " + "</span>" + Math.round(d.Duration) + "\n" +"</span>"; }
    });
    $(element.node()).popover('show');

//Make chosen circle more visible
element.style("opacity", 1)
    .style("stroke-width", 6);

//Append lines to bubbles that will be used to show the precise data points
//vertical line
d3.select(".chordWrapper").append("g")
    .attr("class", "guide")
    .append("line")
        .attr("x1", element.attr("cx"))
        .attr("x2", element.attr("cx"))
        .attr("y1", +element.attr("cy"))
        .attr("y2", (height))
        .style("stroke", element.style("fill"))
        .style("opacity",  0)
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .transition().duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 0.5);
//horizontal line
d3.select(".chordWrapper").append("g")
    .attr("class", "guide")
    .append("line")
        .attr("x1", +element.attr("cx"))
        .attr("x2", 0)
        .attr("y1", element.attr("cy"))
        .attr("y2", element.attr("cy"))
        .style("stroke",  element.style("fill"))
        .style("opacity",  0)
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .transition().duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 0.5);
```

and add :

```
.on("mouseover", showTooltip)
.on("mouseout",  removeTooltip);
```

to your circles (script.js line 84)

take a look here :

https://embed.plnkr.co/86jdbWgHtABY95ZEv9SE/

Comment: Thank you, Lary. Removing .axis .domain helped but tooltip still not working.

Comment: sorry forgot about adding mousover to the circles node (script.js line 84) i edited my answer (i don't know how to update your Plunker...)

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question. In v3 I could show a path to each point on plot like my reference: http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/801c4bb101e86d19a1d0. By mouse over, it showed x-axis and y-axis. When I changed it to v4 I cannot have that anymore. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: you load script.js multiple time in your html, is that wanted?

Comment: Thanks a lot. No, I made a mistake because it was the first time that I used Plunker :) I corrected the link. Thanks for mentioning.